# reactjs giving error module not found

Tags: reactjs

i have 3 components app,header,footer,mid,slide

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import Header from './Header';
  import slide from './slide';
  import Mid from './Mid';
  import Footer from './Footer';

  import './App.css';

  class App extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
        <Header/>
        <slide/>
        <Mid/>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

browser giving me this error

```
Module not found: `E:\reactjs\project-3\template\src\Footer.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `footer.js`.
```

i had saved my footer.js file inside the src folder and export it default my class and file name is in capital letter as well
        import React, {Component} from 'react';

```
class Footer  extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <div class="footer">
          <div class="wrap">
              <div class="f-menu">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="single.html">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Our Works</a></li>
                      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                   <div class="copy">� 2012 Brownie. All rights reserved. Designed by <a href="http://w3layouts.com" style="color:#A68775;"></a> <a href="http://w3layouts.com" style="color:#A68775;">W3Layouts</a></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Footer;
```

Comment: Will it be `./footer` not `./Footer` ? What is the filename you have `footer.js` or `Footer.js` ?

Comment: my file name is Footer.js

Comment: Are you using git in the project?